# Can no longer build Mule projects due to closure of Codehaus

Tags: maven, mule

After the closure of codehaus, I can no longer build any Mule project that uses the mule-scripting-component because it is trying to download an artifact from codehaus(which it can no longer due to the closure of aforementioned site). When I try to build I get the following error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project my.company.muleproject:mule-subproject-page:mule-module:1.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.6.0 -> javax.script:jruby-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.script:jruby-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.script:jruby-engine:pom:1.1 from/to codehaus-mule-repo (http://repository.codehaus.org): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]

What can I do in order to get Mule to ignore the codehaus repo?

Comment: The artifact you need is available in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/javax/script/jruby-engine/1.1/), as codehaus states in the homepage; check your settings.xml or main pomfile for repositories configuration

Comment: Best is start using a repository manager and that's it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already mentioned, setting up a Mirror in your Maven settings.xml will fix it. Just to be a bit more explicit, this is what I added to workaround the issue:

```
<mirror>
  <id>mule-codehaus-mirror</id>
  <mirrorOf>codehaus-mule-repo,codehaus-releases,codehaus-snapshots</mirrorOf>
  <name>Mule Codehaus Mirror</name>
  <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
</mirror>
```

Answer (score 5):

Mulesoft has mirrored and copied the codehaus repository in the following repo:

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/

Answer (score 2):

Although it's in maven central the poms for all the mule libraries still point to codehaus which is causing the error.  I unfortunately had to resort to using mirrors to fix this.  Since all the artifacts are in either maven central or the mule repos, I just added mirrors in my maven's settings.xml to point any and all codehaus repos to maven central.  This is less than ideal but fixed the issue.

Comment: This is not completely correct as not all Mule poms reference the codehaus repository. Some poms that still do has been or are being updated now.